# From Ubuntu recent installation, the suspended session remain blocked, how could I do to solve it?

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I have this [pc](https://www.lenovo.com/it/it/p/laptops/thinkbook/thinkbook-series/thinkbook-15-gen-4-(15-inch-amd)/21dl0046ix), and I mounted on Ubuntu 22.0.4.3 LTS.

From that moment I have the problem that when I suspend my session, if too much time passes (like 2 hours), I am not able to enter again, my mouse became a square and I have to turn off the pc and turn on from 0, and all work again.

Here a photo of what happens when I suspend the session and the screen became locked (I can use mouse. (the image usually is a flower).

[image: display blocked with mouse squared]

I tried a lot to search relative threads already opened, but none was similar to mine, and I tried to do some updates from terminal, but nothing is changed.